# Relative acceleration of one object to another

Tags: homework-and-exercises, relative-motion

Cat A is traveling at a constant positive-x direction of 5m/s. Cat B is accelerating at a 0.5 m/s^2 on the positive-y direction.

The question is:

> What is the acceleration of cat A relative to cat B?

How I thought about it is that if I look at it from the eyes of cat B, then the cat would seem like it would be accelerating to the right and no acceleration on the y. So I would say the relative acceleration would be

a = < 5m/s^2, 0 >

However, I was told that the answer was:

a = < 0, -0.5m/2^s>

Can anyone explain to me how to look at this problem to understand the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cat A is moving with a *constant velocity* of $5.0ms^{-1}$, which means that it is not accelerating.

Cat B would observe Cat A as having a constant velocity in the $x$-direction of $5.0ms^{-1}$, unaffected by Cat B’s acceleration because the two are in different axes, but no relative acceleration in the $x$-direction, because neither Cat A nor Cat B are accelerating in the $x$-direction.

Cat B would observe Cat A as having an acceleration in the $y$-direction of $-0.5ms^{-2}$. Due to Cat A having no vertical or horizontal acceleration, the relative acceleration of Cat A to Cat B is just the opposite of the acceleration of Cat B.

Thus, the acceleration of Cat A relative to Cat B is $[0ms^{-2}, -0.5ms^{-2}]$.

---

In general, if you wish to find the relative motion between two bodies, subtract the velocity (or acceleration) of the body that is the reference frame from the body that is being observer.

Ex. Find body A's velocity relative to body B.

$\vec v_{rel}=\vec v_A-\vec v_B$

or

$\vec v_{rel_x}=\vec v_{A_x} - \vec v_{B_x},\text{ } \vec v_{rel_y}=\vec v_{A_y} - \vec v_{B_y}$

Comment: So would it be correct to say that the relative acceleration of cat A to cat B is the subtraction of the acceleration vector A - acceleration vector B?

Comment: That is generally how you find the relative motion between two bodies, yes (discounting special relativity).